# how to solve vscode prettier putting / in br tag

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[I had some issue asking the question  so I putted a image of my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/helVE.png)

Answer (score -1):

From the prettier.io homepage:

> What is Prettier?
>
> - An opinionated code formatter

So, no you probably can't change that behaviour